# How to Send Email using SPD Workflow ??

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have configured SMTP in IIS and also configured outgoing e-mail settings in Central Administration. But still  I am getting error

"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the outgoing e-mail settings for the server are configured correctly."

I have tried with pause step in SharePoint Designer workflow and SMTP service is also started but no luck....

Answer (score 1):

To make the outgoing e-mail setting to work properly you need to go thruogh all of these steps.

> ### To configure outgoing e-mail for a specific Web application by using Central Administration
>
> 1. Verify that you have the following administrative credentials: You must be a member of the Farm Administrators group on the computer that is running the SharePoint Central Administration Web site.
> 2. In Central Administration, in the Application Management section,
>      click Manage web applications.
> 3. On the Web Applications Management page, select a Web application, and then in the General Settings group on the Ribbon, click Outgoing E-mail.
> 4. On the Web Application Outgoing E-Mail Settings page, in the Mail Settings section, type the SMTP server name for outgoing e-mail (for example, mail.fabrikam.com) in the Outbound SMTP server box.
> 5. In the From address box, type the e-mail address (for example, the site administrator alias) as you want it to be displayed to e-mail recipients.
> 6. In the Reply-to address box, type the e-mail address (for example, a help desk alias) to which you want e-mail recipients to reply.
> 7. In the Character set list, click the character set that is appropriate for your language.
> 8. Click OK.

Reference: [Configure outgoing e-mail (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263462%28v=office.14%29.aspx)